# Swift: different objects in one array?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

Is there a possibility to have two different custom objects in one array?

I want to show two different objects in a `UITableView` and I think the easiest way of doing this is to have all objects in one array.

Comment: As you will manipulate both type of objects, the best practice is to create a `protocol` which all classes implements, MVVM style.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on how much control you want over the array, you can create a protocol that both object types implement.  The protocol doesn't need to have anything in it (would be a marker interface in Java, not sure if there is a specific name in Swift).  This would allow you to limit the array to only the object types you desire.  See the sample code below.

```
protocol MyType {

}


class A: MyType {

}

class B: MyType {

}

var array = [MyType]()

let a = A()
let b = B()

array.append(a)
array.append(b)
```

Comment: Actually, in the protocol I would put al the functions that I am going to invoke in using these objects.  That way you don't have to cast the object to another type to use them and you can be sure the objects support all the functionality you need.

Comment: I won't disagree with that, but if there are no similarities between them, other than wanting to store them in the array for the table view then this method works. With out knowing more about the specific objects, its hard to say what should be in the protocol.  They may already implement some specific protocol and then the solution might simplify down to using that protocol as the type for the array.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for because with anyobject I have to less possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the types of what you will store beforehand, you could wrap them in an enumeration. This gives you more control over the types than using `[Any/AnyObject]`:

```
enum Container {
  case IntegerValue(Int)
  case StringValue(String)
}

var arr: [Container] = [
  .IntegerValue(10),
  .StringValue("Hello"),
  .IntegerValue(42)
]

for item in arr {
  switch item {
  case .IntegerValue(let val):
    println("Integer: \(val)")
  case .StringValue(let val):
    println("String: \(val)")
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Integer: 10
String: Hello
Integer: 42
```

Comment: I found this useful, because I do like that I can use a switch statement to make sure I handle whatever data is in the array.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `AnyObject` array to hold any kind of objects in the same array:

```
var objectsArray = [AnyObject]()
objectsArray.append("Foo")
objectsArray.append(2)

// And also the inmutable version
let objectsArray: [AnyObject] = ["Foo", 2]

// This way you can let the compiler infer the type
let objectsArray = ["Foo", 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "type" `AnyObject` which allows you to store objects of different type in an array. If you also want to use structs, use `Any`:

```
let array: [Any] = [1, "Hi"]
```