# Is there a simple way to store two objects of different type in a container?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to position an SKCameraNode at the center of multiple objects in my scene. I'm thinking of placing all objects of interest into some sort of container, and then calculating the centroid every update(). I have two classes, Ball and Car, that inherit from PhysicalObject, which inherits from SKSpriteNode. What I'd like to do is something like

```
var cameraObjects: Array<Ball, Car>!
...
var ball1 = Ball()
var car1 = Car()
cameraObjects.append(ball1)
cameraObjects.append(car1)
...
// Loop through objects and calculate centroid
```

But this crashes at the first append().

Note that I'd rather not create a dummy protocol for each class, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548239/swift-different-objects-in-one-array). Is there a simple way to do this?

PhysicalObject.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class PhysicalObject: SKSpriteNode {

    var objectMass: CGFloat!

    override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        self.name = "physicalObject"

        //Physics setup
        physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Ball.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class Ball: PhysicalObject {

    let MAXBALLSPEED :CGFloat = 0.08

    init(spawnPosition: CGPoint) {

        /* Temporary initialization.. will have further customization for different classes */
        let ballTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
        let ballRadius = CGFloat(50)
        let ballSize = CGSize(width: ballRadius, height: ballRadius)

        super.init(texture: ballTexture, color: UIColor.clear, size: ballSize)

        self.position = spawnPosition

        self.name = "ball"

        //Physics Setup
        //self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(origin: spawnPosition, size: carSize) )
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.height/2)
        self.objectMass = CGFloat(0.005)
        physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // Default is true
        physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0


        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boards | PhysicsCategory.Car


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Car.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class Car: PhysicalObject {

    let MAXCARSPEED: CGFloat = 500
    var steering: Bool
    var diagonalLength: CGFloat

    init(spawnPosition: CGPoint) {

        /* Temporary initialization.. will have further customization for different classes of cars */
        let carTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BasicCar")
        let carWidth = CGFloat(screenSize.width/20)
        let carScale = CGFloat(183.0/140.0)
        let carSize = CGSize(width: (carWidth*carScale), height: carWidth)

        // Initialize movement variables
        self.steering = false
        self.diagonalLength = hypot(carSize.width, carSize.height)

        //self.steerRight = false
        //self.steerLeft = false

        super.init(texture: carTexture, color: UIColor.clear, size: carSize)


        self.speed = CGFloat(MAXCARSPEED)
        self.position = spawnPosition
        self.name = "car"

        //Physics Setup
        //self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(origin: spawnPosition, size: carSize) )
        let carPhysicsSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: carPhysicsSize)
        self.objectMass = CGFloat(2000)
        self.physicsBody?.friction = 0.5
        self.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1.0
        self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.0
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
        physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // Default is true


        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Car
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Car | PhysicsCategory.Ball


    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `[PhysicalObject]`? there is no point to have dummy protocol because they already share a common base class

Comment: The way you setup that array is wack. And it initalizes to nil the way you have it set up which explains your crash because you are trying to append to nil.

Comment: Array<Ball, Car> shouldn't even compile...are you overriding the array class or something?

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah I tried Array<PhysicalObject> earlier and it crashed too. At least I know why now thanks to @NSGangster.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Sorry, that was deceivingly realistic pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `Array<PhysicalObject>` (a.k.a. `[PhysicalObject]`), which can store both `Ball` objects, and `Car` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that the `enumerateChildNodes` method of `SKNode` is a better way to enumerate over all the objects with a certain name. That way, you don't need to manage the array yourself.

Take a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodes).

Comment: I will definitely use this. I didn't know you could use regex to find nodes!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is place all the objects you want be involved with the camera into a new parent SKNode, and use `calculateAccumulatedFrame` to get the frame around all the nodes, then just use the center of the parent's frame.

Comment: Ah another useful bit of information. I will use this.